# Deriving value from a string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a column called NARRATION in my table and it has values like as shown below.

```
NARRATION
-------------------------------------
BI DS NO 6005527182
BI DS NO. 485019
CI DS NO.6008364862(2000*1) 
CI DS NO.1905180207 10*1) EDDF34592845
CI DS NO.2105180520-(50*1) DDFF39844240
CI DS NO.2105180653 (2000*1) DFSD39844240
CI DS NO.1905180220/(500*3,20
CI DS NO.2105180166*(200*1) DSFSF39844240
```

I want to derive first word after the text **DS NO.** till the next space or any other special character like as shown below.
Some times there might be space also exists after **DS NO.** and from the space word starts that i need to derive.

```
NARRATION                                 |DERIVE_NARRATION  
------------------------------------------|----------------
BI DS NO 6005527182                       |6005527182
BI DS NO. 485019                          |485019
CI DS NO.6008364862(2000*1)               |6008364862
CI DS NO.1905180207 10*1) EDDF34592845    |1905180207
CI DS NO.2105180520-(50*1) DDFF39844240   |2105180520
CI DS NO.2105180653 (2000*1) DFSD39844240 |2105180653
CI DS NO. 1905180220/(500*3,20            |1905180220
CI DS NO.2105180166*(200*1) DSFSF39844240 |2105180166
```

Please help me query.

Comment: Is your "word" after DO always a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_substr`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099) to get what you need.
Assuming that your "special chars" are all listed in your sample data, this should do the job

```
select narration,
       regexp_substr(narration, 'DS NO([ \.]*)([^- \\/\*(]*)', 1, 1, 'i', 2)
from tab

NARRATION                                 DERIVE_NARRATION
----------------------------------------- ----------------------------
BI DS NO 6005527182                       6005527182
BI DS NO. 485019                          485019
CI DS NO.6008364862(2000*1)               6008364862
CI DS NO.1905180207 10*1) EDDF34592845    1905180207
CI DS NO.2105180520-(50*1) DDFF39844240   2105180520
CI DS NO.2105180653 (2000*1) DFSD39844240 2105180653
CI DS NO. 1905180220/(500*3,20            1905180220
CI DS NO.2105180166*(200*1) DSFSF39844240 2105180166
```

How it works: it looks for the string "DS NO" followed by spaces or dots and then gets the following characters, going onward until it finds a "special char", listed in `[^- \\/\*(]`. 
The parameter 2 is used to get the second matching expression.

With that sample data, it seems that you need to get a number, more that everything up to a "special char"; if so, you can edit it into:

```
regexp_substr(narration, 'DS NO([ \.]*)([0-9]*)', 1, 1, 'i', 2)
```